# Remove tab, new line, carriage return until encountered char

Tags: sed, awk

I have a CSV file that has record separator of `,\n`. One of the columns, has the possibility of containing tabs and new lines, which I wish to remove. How do I remove these chars (`\t\n\r`) using `sed` and/or `awk`, until encountering the record separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
cat input_file | tr -d '\r\t' | sed ': loop_start; /,$/b; N; s/\n//; b loop_start'
```

Explanation:

1. `tr` is used to delete (`-d`) all `\r` and `\t` chars.
2. Then sed loops (`: loop_start; ...; b loop_start`) and
3. joins all lines (`N`) and
4. removes the newline (`s/\n//`)
5. until it finds the record separator (`/,$/`) and
6. branches to the end of the script (`b`) where it will start the script over with the next line of input.